# Xamarin BLE Plugin connect to device after app restart

Tags: xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am writing an app in Xamarin.Forms that is using the BLE Plugin to discover BLE Devices, connects to them and exchanges information.

**When I close the app and restart it, how is it possible to reconnect to the same devices again?**

I don't want to go through the discoveryloop again if possible.
I persisted their Guid and tried to use the method ConnectToKnownDeviceAsync(), but i only get a NullReferenceException, probably because after the restart i have no "ConnectedDevices" anymore. Is there any way to store the IDevice information and reuse it?

Answer (score -1):

**Here you can persist the information using** 
[Xamarin.Essentials: Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?tabs=android)

When your app wakeup you can get value and reconnect automatically.

Comment: not sure how it is going to work. i checked the documentation you liked to and it said only primitives and datetime is allowed. I figured i could save a json string but when i tried to serialize the object it threw the following exception: System.NotImplementedException: 'Derived classes must implement it' -- i assume it's because IDevice is an interface? I have no access to the implementation of IDevice.